# speak.js compiling issues in windows

Tags: cygwin, llvm, llvm-clang, emscripten, espeak

I'm having this issue when trying to compile `speak.js`. In `emscripten.sh` when the compiler reaches this line:

```
$EMSCRIPTEN/emcc -O2 --js-transform "python bundle.py" speak.bc -o speak.raw.js
```

I get this error (previous parts work fine):

```
emscripten

fs.js:338
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\tmp\tmp0Ak4ij.txt' 
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18) 
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:182:15) 
    at read (C:\opt\emscripten\src\compiler.js:36:37) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\opt\emscripten\src\compiler.js:120:29) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/emscripten/emcc", line 871, in <module>
    final = shared.Building.emscripten(final, append_ext=False, extra_args=extra_args)
  File "/opt/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 736, in emscripten
    assert os.path.exists(filename + '.o.js') and len(open(filename + '.o.js', 'r').read()) > 0, 'Emscripten failed to generate .js: ' + str(compiler_output)
AssertionError: Emscripten failed to generate .js:
cat: speak.raw.js: No such file or directory
```

I'm running cygwin under windows 7; all emscripten sanity checks worked fine, and I tried changing emscripten /tmp config (.escripten in the home folder) to several values, granting permissions, etc. It seems that the temp file is never created, so when it tries to access it again, it breaks.

Any help/guidance/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what the script is doing. You might get to a solution faster, if you get into the _Emscripten_ IRC channel and bug azakai about it :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't know which is the emscripten irc any URL, link?

Comment: Found it (sorry for the laziness) IRC: #emscripten on irc.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested , I'm posting an answer.

unfortunately, I couldn't find the underlying cause, but it doesn't work with cygwin under windows 7 x64.

I was able to compile, however, installing clang, llvm visual studio express ant the rest of the tools in this link

[Using emscripten with VS 2010](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Using-Emscripten-from-Visual-Studio-2010)

and do the same thing that's in emscripten.sh with windows console. However it won´t compile with

> emcc -O2 --js-transform "python bundle.py" speak.bc -o speak.raw.js

you have to remove the ***-02*** option, and it works. I'm testing the different languages/phonemes and let you know how does it work